# Image processing output gives black image

Tags: java, image-processing

So, just posted earlier about trying to finish my comp sci project. I basically finished everything I needed to do but, I was trying to get this image to rotate 90 degrees, but when i open the outputted image, its all black. I'm not sure what is wrong with it.

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Project6b
{
public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
{


rotate90ToLeft("Jack.jpg","Jack2.jpg");
}

public static void rotate90ToLeft(String originalImage, String convertedImage) throws Exception
{

  BufferedImage bufferImg = ImageIO.read(new File(originalImage));
  BufferedImage bufferImgOut = new      BufferedImage(bufferImg.getWidth(),bufferImg.getHeight(), bufferImg.getType());


for( int x = 0; x < bufferImg.getWidth(); x++ )
{
    for( int y = 0; y < bufferImg.getHeight(); y++ )
    {
        int px = bufferImg.getRGB(x, y);
        int destY = bufferImg.getWidth() - x - 1;
        bufferImgOut.setRGB(y,destY, px);

    }
}
   File outputfile = new File(convertedImage);
    ImageIO.write(bufferImgOut, "png", outputfile);


}
 }
```

Okay, I figured out that the image has to be smaller than 400x400. Is there any way I can make it work for any size image?

Comment: Is half your code commented out for a reason?

Comment: Yeah because I was only testing that method. The other 2 work.

Comment: Code works on an image for me locally; try another image to and see if it works.

Comment: Shouldn't you be creating the output image like this:   BufferedImage bufferImgOut = new      BufferedImage(bufferImg.getHeight(),bufferImg.getWidth(), bufferImg.getType());

Comment: You should try to only post the code relevant to the problem, help people help you :)

Comment: Okay, i got it. It has to be a square in order for it to work. Thank you though!